# Match but exclude a string using C# regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to extract 01, which follows -ADP- out of below string using C# regular expressions.

> 04152017-ADP-01-837P-999-04152017-922{C058EA71-46F9-48C6-A48E-67E61F5F7AEC}

I have so far looked into other questions here and also looked into non capturing group, look-ahead, but no luck yet.

Best regex i have so far is:

```
(?:-ADP-)\d{2}
```

This produces -ADP-01, but not 01.

Comment: `(?<=\-ADP\-)\d{2}`: try look behind https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: You mean "which follows -ADP-". 'Precede' would be to the left.

Comment: Thanks you, that works!!

Comment: Use `var m = Regex.Match(s, @"-ADP-(\d{2})")` and then `if (m.Success)` grab `m.Groups[1].Value`. Learn about [capturing groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)/[backreferences](https://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html).

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes, thanks, i have corrected it in the question.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, as the way test strings are constructed, i do not expect more than one matching result and since regexes are stored as configurations inside the code, i prefer to get the first result and not going through the array.